# WPF Telerik RadGridView prevents button clicking when cell value is invalid

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, telerik

I have a `telerik:RadGridView` cell with validation that works as intended; however, in the cases where the cell is invalid, all the buttons on that same window don't respond. I added code to disable my 'Done' button (`btnDone`) whenever the cell validity is invalid *(see below)*, however my 'Cancel' button (`btnCancel`) should always work, regardless of the validity of the cell contents. The button looks like it's clickable, but even when I put a breakpoint inside the Click action on that button... it doesn't trigger the event.

**ButtonChooser.xaml**

```xml
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="gridSelectedControls" CanUserInsertRows="False"
    CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False"
    SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="FullRow"
    ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedControls}"
    CellValidating="RadGridViewCellValidating">
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="ValueTextCell" UniqueName="Description"
            DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Text, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            IsReadOnly="False" HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource HeaderCell}">
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Header>
                <TextBlock x:Name="textBlockLabelText" Text="header" />
            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Header>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox x:Name="tbDisplayText" MaxLength="255" Text="TestDataText" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
        </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
    </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
</telerik:RadGridView>

<!-- More unrelated code between -->

<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1">
    <Button x:Name="btnDone" Content="Done" IsDefault="True" Click="OnDoneButtonClick" />
    <Button x:Name="btnCancel" Content="Cancel" IsDefault="False" IsCancel="True" Click="OnCancelButtonClick" />
</StackPanel>
```

**ButtonChooser.xaml.cs**

```cs
private void RadGridViewCellValidating(object sender, GridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    e.IsValid = true;

    if (string.Compare(e.Cell.Column.UniqueName, "Description") == 0 && e.EditingElement is TextBox element)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(element.Text))
        {
            e.IsValid = false;
            e.ErrorMessage = "Too empty";
        }

        if (element.Text.Length > 255)
        {
            e.IsValid = false;
            e.ErrorMessage = "Too much not empty";
        }

        btnDone.IsEnabled = e.IsValid;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

I tried putting a breakpoint in the 'Click' trigger of the buttons, but they never fired. I also tried adding an event during the `BeginningEdit` and `cellEditEnded` events of the RadGridView to force the button to `btnCancel.IsEnable = true` but that also didn't do anything.